# Python: speed up pow(base,exp,mod) for fixed exp and mod, or with vectorization

Tags: python, modulo, number-theory, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

The bottleneck of my code is the repeated calling of pow(base,exponent,modulus) for very large integers (numpy does not support such large integers, about 100 to 256 bits).
However, my exponent and modulus is always the same. Could I somehow utilize this to speed the computation up with a custom function?
I tried to define a function as seen below (function below is for general modulus and exponent).

However, even if I hardcode every operation without the while-loop and if-statements for a fixed exponent and modulus, it is slower than pow.

```
def modular_pow(self, base, exponent, modulus):
    result = 1
    base = base % modulus
    while exponent > 0:
        if (exponent % 2 == 1):
            result = (result * base) % modulus
        exponent = exponent >> 1
        base = (base * base) % modulus
    return result
```

Another option would be if I can somehow "vectorize" it. I have to compute pow for about 100000000 different base values. While these values often change between my script runs (so a look up table will not be useful), I will know these values the moment I hit run (I could compute them all at once).

Any ideas?
I got some speedup by using mpz datatypes from gmpy2, but it still is too slow.

Comment: The code isn't indented correctly.

Comment: I think by vectorize you mean [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: If by memoization you mean look-up table, this won't work, the base values are unique and change too often.

Comment: Try gmpy2 - Python's arbitrary-precision int implementation isn't designed for speed.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica as mentioned at the end of my question, I am already using gmpy2 mpz datatypes. If you are referin to a specific function, could you please let me know which and how to use it. Thank you

Comment: Oh, you did mention that. You did use `gmpy2.powmod` or the built-in 3-argument `pow` with those data types, rather than your own implementation, right? Their implementation is going to be a lot faster than yours.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I am using:
"gmpy2.powmod(base,exponent,modulus)" from gmpy2, which for me is speedwise equivalent to using "pow(mpz(base),mpz(exponent),mpz(modulus)" with "from gmpy2 import mpz".
I was hoping there would be anything else I could optimize, given that my exponent and modulus is always fixed, or the fact that I already know all the base-values at the time of execution

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do, then.

Comment: Can you please give us some information about the data that you are using? Is base an integer? Can it be stored in a standard 32 bit integer? And what about exponent and modulus? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news, bad news. Good news is that when the modulus `m` is fixed, there *are* ways to speed computing `a*b % m`. Search for "Barrett reduction" and "Montgomery reduction". They work, in different ways, by precomputing constants related to `m` such that `% m` can be computed via multiplication and shifting, without needing division.

The bad news: to find the remainder, both ways require (in addition to cheaper operations) two multiplications.  So they don't pay overall unless multiplication is much cheaper than division.

For that reason, they're generally slower unless the modulus is "truly" large - your "about 100 to 256 bits" is still on the small side by modern standards, just a few times wider than native 64-bit machine ints. Things like speedy FFT-based multiplication require much larger integers before they pay off.

CPython's built-in modular pow is already using a "binary" scheme, along the lines of what you coded in Python, but fancier (if the exponent is "large enough", the built-in pow views it as being in base 32, consuming 5 exponent bits per loop iteration).

In a quick stab implementing Montgomery reduction in Python, and replacing the modular multiplies in your code by the Montgomery spellings, `modular_pow()` didn't get faster than the built-in before the modulus grew to tens of thousands of bits. For inputs around 256 bits, it was about 3x slower.

That's a mixed bag: the Python code didn't exploit the "base 32" tricks, which can give substantial benefits. But for large enough inputs, CPython uses faster-than-naïve Karatsuba multiplication, which the division-free Montgomery spelling can benefit from (CPython's int division has no speedup tricks regardless of input sizes, and CPython's built-in modular pow always uses division to find remainders).

So, short course: there's nothing I know of obvious you can do in CPython to speed a single instance of `pow(a, b, c)`. It's possible some C-coded crypto library out there has something suitable, but not that I know of.

But the other good news is that your problem is "embarrassingly parallel". If you have N processors, you can give each of them 100000000/N of your inputs, and they can all run full speed in parallel. That would give a speedup of about a factor of N.

But the bad news is that your integers really aren't "large" (they're small enough that I bet you can still compute thousands of modular pows per second with the built-in pow), and interprocess communication costs may wipe out the benefits of doing N computations in parallel. That all depends on exactly how you get your inputs and what you want to do with the results.

### FOLLOW UP

The "Handbook of Applied Cryptography" (HAC), [chapter 14](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf), essentially spells out the state of the art for gonzo modular exponentiation algorithms.

Looking into the code, GMP already implements every trick they have. This includes the things I mentioned (Montgomery reduction, and using a power-of-2 base higher than 2 to chew up more exponent bits per loop iteration). And others I didn't mention (e.g., GMP has a special internal routine for squaring, which saves cycles over a general product of possibly unequal integers). In all, it's a small mountain of implementation code.

I expect that's why you're not getting more answers: GMP is already doing, at worst, close to the best anyone has ever figured out how to do. The speedup for you isn't truly dramatic because, as already noted, the integers you're using are actually on the small side.

So if you need to pursue this, using GMP is likely the fastest you're going to get. As noted, multiprocessing is an obvious way to get a theoretical N-fold speedup with N processors, but as also noted you haven't said anything about the context (where these inputs come from or what you need to do with the outputs). So it's impossible to guess whether that might pay off for you. The more interprocess communication you need, the more that damages potential multiprocessing speedups.

Note: what you're doing is exactly what, e.g., RSA public-key cryptosystems do, although they generally use larger integers. That is, your "base" is their "message", and a public (or private) RSA key consists of a fixed exponent and fixed modulus. Only the base (message or encrypted bits) varies across en/de-cryption instances. For a given key, the exponent and modulus are always the same.

Many world-class mathematicians have studied the problem, and world-class hackers coded the algorithms for peak speed. That's why you should give up hope on that there's a faster way that HAC just forgot to mention ;-)

### Speculative

Drawing the connection to RSA reminded me: RSA decryption, in practice, does *not* proceed in "the obvious" way. Instead, the holder of the private key knows the prime factorization of the key's modulus (in RSA, the modulus is the product of two distinct - but kept secret -large primes), and that can be used to significantly speed exponentiation with respect to that modulus.

So (can't guess), if the way you get your modulus instances is such that you can compute their prime factorizations efficiently, that can be used to get significant speedups, when they're composite.

Not so much for a prime modulus, though. About the only *highly* potentially valuable trick then is that, for `p` prime and `a` not divisible by `p`,

```
pow(a, b, p) == pow(a, b % (p-1), p)
```

That can save unbounded time if `b` can be much larger than `p`. It works because, by Fermat's little theorem,

```
pow(a, p-1, p) == 1
```

for `p` prime and `a` not divisible by `p`.  For example,

```py
>>> p
2347
>>> assert all(p % i != 0 for i in range(2, p))  # that is, p is prime
>>> pow(345, 1000000000000000000000000000000, p)
301
>>> 1000000000000000000000000000000 % (p-1)
1198
>>> pow(345, 1198, p) # same thing, but much faster
301
```

For a composite modulus, much the same is done for each of its prime power factors, and then the results are pasted together via the Chinese remainder theorem.

*If* you think your problem can be worked to exploit that, search for "modular exponentiation Chinese remainder" to find a number of good expositions.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to implement and compare several methods in Python (without C/C++). To tell in advance, with following my code I reached **25x** times speedup compared to using Python's [pow(a, b, c)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) Some methods are parallelized, some not.

**Note**: See updated Part 2 of my post below with C++ code.

See code at the very bottom of this post. Timings below will be for my i7 laptop with 4 cores at 1.2 Ghz (8 hardware threads).

1. `Python` - Pure Python single-process. This method does list comprehension with [pow(a, b, c)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) built-in python function.
2. `Python_Parallel` - Multi-process pure Python. Same as method 1) but parallel. This and further methods use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to occupy all CPU cores.
3. `Gmp` - [GMPY2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)-based single-process solution. This uses [powmod()](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html) function and list comprehension.
4. `Gmp_Parallel` - Parallel GMPY2-based. Uses method 3) but on all cores.
5. `Redc_Div_Parallel` - Binary exponentiation (also known as [Exponentiation by Squarings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)) with regular modulus computation through `% mod` operation. This and further methods also use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays with Python objects (`object` dtype). This and further methods implement [Windowed Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Windowed_method) to boost exponentiation.
6. `Redc_Barrett_Parallel` - Same as 5) but uses [Barrett Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm) to replace division by multiplications.
7. `Redc_Montgomery_Parallel` - Same as 5) but uses [Montgomery Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/montgomery-reduction-algorithm) to replace division.

---

Timings:

```
Python                    : time  78.74 sec, boost  1.00
Python_Parallel           : time  19.09 sec, boost  4.12, Correct
Gmp                       : time  27.76 sec, boost  2.84, Correct
Gmp_Parallel              : time   7.57 sec, boost 10.40, Correct
Redc_Div_Parallel         : time  17.38 sec, boost  4.53, Correct, w = 4 (324 redcs)
Redc_Barrett_Parallel     : time  33.15 sec, boost  2.38, Correct, w = 4 (324 redcs)
Redc_Montgomery_Parallel  : time  42.24 sec, boost  1.86, Correct, w = 4 (324 redcs)
```

All timings above measure boost compared to `Python` (single-threaded) base. Correctness of all computed results is checked compared to `Python` output.

One can see that `Gmp_Parallel` gives the biggest boost, also it is very simple, just two lines of code. Probably among Python-only solutions it is the best and most simple.

Of course if you convert `Redc_...` methods to C/C++, they should become much faster, and could be faster than GMP C method [mpz_powm](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation) (which is a base of GMPY2's `powmod()`). You can use fixed-arithmetics [_ExtInt](https://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html) type available in [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), just do `using u512 = unsigned _ExtInt(512);` and you'll get fixed-size 512-bit integer type for free, you can even put any large non-even number of bits like `_ExtInt(12345)`. Also [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_int_ref.html) has `uint128_t`/`uint256_t`/`uint512_t` available in C++.

I can imagine the only reason that Barrett/Montgomery solutions are slower only because they are Python-object based, so most of time is spent in organizing Python interactions instead of doing simple mul/shift operations without division. Hence if you use C++ you'll get much speed improvement.

In my code below you can tweak variables `num_bits` and `pow_bits` to set size of numbers (in bits) and size of powers, also `cnt_nums` sets size of array (numbers of bases to be power-rised).

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67664402#main.py)

```py
def PowModPython(bs, e, m):
    return [pow(b, e, m) for b in bs]

def PowModGmp(bs, e, m):
    import gmpy2, numpy as np
    return [gmpy2.powmod(b, e, m) for b in bs]
    #return list(np.vectorize(lambda x: gmpy2.powmod(x, e, m))(np.asarray(bs, dtype = object)))

def PowModParallel(func, bs, e, m, *, processes = None, extra = ()):
    import multiprocessing as mp, functools
    if processes is None:
        processes = mp.cpu_count()
    with mp.Pool(processes) as pool:
        try:
            block = (len(bs) + processes * 8 - 1) // (processes * 8)
            return functools.reduce(
                lambda a, b: a + b,
                pool.starmap(func,
                    [(bs[i : i + block], e, m) + extra for i in range(0, len(bs), block)]),
                []
            )
        finally:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

def PowModRedc(bs, e, m, bits, redc_type = None, w = None):
    import gmpy2, numpy as np, math

    def Int(x):
        return gmpy2.mpz(x)
    def Mask(x, s):
        #return x & ((1 << s) - 1)
        return np.vectorize(lambda x: gmpy2.t_mod_2exp(x, s))(x)

    e = Int(e)
    m = Int(m)
    
    def CreateMod():
        if redc_type == 'div':
            def Mod(x):
                return x % m
            def To(x):
                return x
            def From(x):
                return x
            def Adjust(x):
                return x
        else:
            if redc_type is None and m & 1 != 0 or redc_type == 'montgomery':
                # https://www.nayuki.io/page/montgomery-reduction-algorithm

                assert m & 1 != 0, 'Montgomery can not handle even modulus!'

                def MontgomeryPrec(n, s):
                    n, s = Int(n), Int(s)
                    r = 1 << s
                    r2 = (r * r) % n
                    ri = pow(r, -1, n)
                    k = (r * ri - 1) // n
                    return n, s, Int(k), Int(r2), Int(r - 1)
                
                Mg = MontgomeryPrec(m, bits + 2)
                
                def Mod(x):
                    n, s, k, _, mask = Mg
                    t = Mask(Mask(x, s) * k, s)
                    u = (x + t * n) >> s
                    return u
                    
                def To(x):
                    _, _, _, r2, _ = Mg
                    return Mod(x * r2)

                def From(x):
                    return Mod(x)
            elif redc_type == 'barrett':
                # https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm

                assert m > 0 and m & (m - 1) != 0, 'Modulus is a power of two! Not possible for Barrett.'

                def BarrettPrec(n, s):
                    n, s = Int(n), Int(s)
                    return n, s, (1 << s) // n

                Br = BarrettPrec(m, bits * 2 + 2)

                def Mod(x):
                    n, s, r = Br
                    q = (x * r) >> s
                    u = x - q * n
                    return u

                def To(x):
                    return x
                
                def From(x):
                    return x
            else:
                assert False, f'Unknown reduction type {redc_type}!'

            def Adjust(x):
                gm = x >= m
                x[gm] -= m
                return x

        return Mod, To, From, Adjust
    
    def Arr(x):
        return np.array([Int(e) for e in  x], dtype = object)
    
    Mod, To, From, Adjust = CreateMod()
    bs = To(Mod(To(Arr(bs))))

    if w is None:
        w = OptW(e)[1]
    
    def PreComputePowers(d, w, bs):
        d = Int(d)
        digits = []
        mask = 2 ** w - 1
        while d != 0:
            digits.append(d & mask)
            d >>= w
        digits = digits[::-1]
        powers = [None, np.copy(bs)]
        for i in range(2, 2 ** w):
            powers.append(Mod(powers[-1] * bs))
        return digits, powers
    
    digits, powers = PreComputePowers(e, w, bs)
    res = powers[digits[0]]
    
    for digit in digits[1:]:
        for i in range(w):
            res = Mod(res * res)
        if digit != 0:
            res = Mod(res * powers[digit])
    
    return list(Adjust(From(res)))

def OptW(e):
    n = max(1, e.bit_length())
    minv = None
    for w in range(1, 11):
        # Number of multiplication-reductions
        c = (2 ** w - 2) + ((n - 1) // w) * (w + 1)
        if minv is None or c < minv[0]:
            minv = (c, w)
    return minv

def Test():
    import time, random, numpy as np
    random.seed(0)
    
    num_bits = 496
    pow_bits = 252
    cnt_nums = 1 << 16
    cnt_pows = 1 << 0
    
    def Rand(bits):
        return random.randrange(1 << bits)
    
    bs = [Rand(num_bits) for i in range(cnt_nums)]
    em = [(Rand(pow_bits), Rand(num_bits) | 1) for i in range(cnt_pows)]

    opt_w = OptW(em[0][0])
    ref_tim, res = None, None
    for fname, f, w in [
        ('Python', PowModPython, None),
        ('Python_Parallel', lambda bs, e, m: PowModParallel(PowModPython, bs, e, m), None),
        ('Gmp', PowModGmp, None),
        ('Gmp_Parallel', lambda bs, e, m: PowModParallel(PowModGmp, bs, e, m), None),
        ('Redc_Div_Parallel', lambda bs, e, m: PowModParallel(PowModRedc, bs, e, m, extra = (num_bits, 'div')), opt_w),
        ('Redc_Barrett_Parallel', lambda bs, e, m: PowModParallel(PowModRedc, bs, e, m, extra = (num_bits, 'barrett')), opt_w),
        ('Redc_Montgomery_Parallel', lambda bs, e, m: PowModParallel(PowModRedc, bs, e, m, extra = (num_bits, 'montgomery')), opt_w),
    ]:
        tim = time.time()
        for e, m in em:
            resc = f(bs, e, m)
        tim = time.time() - tim
        if ref_tim is None:
            ref_tim = tim
        print(f'{fname:<26}: time {tim:>6.02f} sec, boost {ref_tim / tim:>5.02f}', end = '', flush = True)
        if res is not None:
            assert np.all(np.equal(res, resc))
            print(', Correct', end = '')
        else:
            res = resc
        print(f', w = {w[1]} ({w[0]} redcs)' if w is not None else '')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```

---

**Update**. Also implemented C++ version together with [Cython](https://cython.org/) to adopt it to run in Python. See following code at the bottom. Also I used [Sliding Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Sliding-window_method) approach instead of [Regular Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Windowed_method) used above.

C++ paralel version (Montgomery-based) appeared to be `2x` times faster than GMPY2 parallel implemented above (and `19x` times faster than Python single-threaded version). Barrett version appeared `1.1x` times faster than parallel GMP. Precise timings below, see `Cython_...` variants, they are fastest:

```
reg_win = 4 (328 redcs), slide_win = 5 (320 redcs)

Python                           : time  78.90 sec, boost  1.00
Python_Parallel                  : time  20.22 sec, boost  3.90, Correct
Gmp                              : time  27.81 sec, boost  2.84, Correct
Gmp_Parallel                     : time   8.19 sec, boost  9.63, Correct
Redc_Div_Parallel                : time  17.42 sec, boost  4.53, Correct
Redc_Barrett_Parallel            : time  33.08 sec, boost  2.39, Correct
Redc_Montgomery_Parallel         : time  43.05 sec, boost  1.83, Correct
Cython_Redc_Barrett_Parallel     : time   7.71 sec, boost 10.23, Correct
Cython_Redc_Montgomery_Parallel  : time   4.15 sec, boost 19.00, Correct
```

C++ version uses features of C++20 standard. Also it needs [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler, because it uses `_ExtInt(N)` type available in Clang only. For long arithmetics it uses [Boost](https://www.boost.org/). For parallelization it uses [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) technology built-in in compiler.

Cython package should be installed in Python, because Cython is reponsible for wrapping and compiling C++. Install it through `python -m pip install cython`.

On Windows you can install Clang from [releases](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) page, download and install `LLVM-13.0.0-win64.exe`. Boost can be installed by [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), it is a great package manager for Windows, or downloaded from [Boost website](https://www.boost.org/users/download/). To install it with Chocolatey just type `choco install boost-msvc-14.2` in console. Also on Windows you should install [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.com/), 2019 or 2022 version, Community variant is enough. Visual Studio is needed because Clang depends on its libraries on Windows, only on Linux/MacOS Clang is independent.

Under Linux Clang and Boost can be installed just through `sudo apt install clang libboost-all-dev`.

In my code below you can see `clang_dir = 'c:/bin/llvm/bin/', boost_dir = None` in `cython_import()` function. You should set these two options only under Windows, for Linux set them to `clang_dir = '', boost_dir = ''`. Chocolatey installs Boost into `c:/local/boost_1_74_0/` directory by default.

**Sources Here**. Source code with C++ appeared to be too large for StackOverflow post size limit (30 000 chars), hence I uploaded this code to PasteBin, it can be downloaded [from here](https://pastebin.com/raw/C4XPNpzG) (`Tio.run` mirror [is here](https://tio.run/##1T1rc9s4kt/9KzBObUTalCwpiTcnP@4SO5NLVZLJJt6avdKqWBQFSbTEx5CUJY/Hv32uuwGS4FNSHlu7KpdNAY1Gd6NfAAg4uI/nvvfszz8nfMo@@esP/uQTFWnjyGDcYK4@OGDwCXm8Cj02DPy1NpY1bOqHbMwcj42j0cFBhuKtGxTbO27ghzGbucF932DeCv4yK2JekMNO1R3ow/UnNd0g@BMJv3SiWPOCzh23Yz90fufa0nLHE4ttBiyHaiNR6QhtRVYYWvdE4SS@Dzi7YP74FnDouq6y8ckKreWSL7XpyrMNlnBksCODBaFv8yjiETT@6HtQzjdxaME3Tc@z7K6WsSPBHW@GXLuBwRBn7PvLSMBOFYxORCgFFvyonblBxw5Wpu2vvFjTCWTtxHMs/wTotBRWx54CKMrwxOF99gU/46VvL5DmJccR19mx0tcRe8narKezkxOm5Yr1HBI5GClDnZBPVjbXckD4kYNjgSgHzIK@xkYJBgnuRLEVulYg5F4Cwc8QqB06bMAcRINcjBJtOZYjgVrjoNaEljfjWtdgkklDNNBHehn3cJQryhidOh7oQkF8RKy99COu6eWKW9/xtJxCfeYTW8vUaOzE8AzSsk2phkKT1vJpm@kAEiueHxAQdvIONGKjZyTKgRGW4Aa/Q2UK@8GKFmgWkQKfmNWGPWWa1mPn51BNKlBE2WhzsQkmZ/b5JhAd6NgvYUAWkUguELryqyu@prRdhdyKOchLU4gDC1EkdcFaE@eulR8O4gutXR@UBjZl7S/MLTW68RvblOB/Dn13vxavJrerKN6tDV9GPA@W4116B2Z5E5DgU9ZjP12wLgNtz8vH9b145rs8vG@VO33C5nEcRIOTk/V63fGs@9XC6Tj@SWDN@EnWsk2mHDu@17aWMxjueO4elJBZ4BfQ0aXEGKz1IcXBbAsUxo/ZHChecsbvuMdAQ1bLVfRTq4xNjGLS@lPIbc3L66n6wSqpRh5YNv6N9ErIEMCETldX99EPhuDeQh2UxKsGcgAIQ2BosHYPjLG6q0WKykk9aA1CaU/AhSB@IZkI@8lD3gCTT6ngwww6LchN@hhwif0dMDSZTyJqgy0MZqLjiZDJD7NKyBir0MFkXgaEscC/lfArlNcGyIwBzNPZ5WXdIAlxrSorKxmqMW38mIb8CcGtmvXcyE5JNDimfb1aaWu9QhFJXgh8WXJtY0hQeBzva7ey2Z5GewnOI/Elmiv0NTVislJ0ORaqPQ@ZP2Xx2v8JXFAMJZDRjMGkMdS@Fp13aixaVn9Hc1YtJw1WZGgl@Ndo@yoFiWEcsb4wjq80BsIbVgL8JnSa3EmtPqPib0Dkv6HeN2v8vtpdGYpqzWQX3d0U1LYYpRSt@tmCWshxW3/3Fp6/9liqkoyU/CHV98diCNgSLWcuiezyohDG8bOB@cOItauqUhYOygZpgBgNkoAhe86nI6/CsCqtwpkEzSOGIqUhK@CYcLLNqDSzyFBW9giAStZDcGM0BBhgLIE/SAUkrzRFkTnBujxTwNTxlyD@FegZ9kZ5PkDzr3w3WMX8E5pypAEda5zWKLxNpPFNMqObODM0lQs1N5buv8@OjqBLcBkZAXMHHMKEPEghOyM8HSsIuDfRJuBtEEveuCdgKhdsXe5bPAwHg3Yvo4I8ElEm8mYYEdsPcGKnZ0CFaQC4ekG1XkzlEVdCHcpclAyhQzBOlHxRAQRNhmyqyDpXDuSVBM8TwcvJbySyCuxOMtodKYOHLFA5siEBeoPRoI7HIm@iA@QppPkb/NbVvFrgLo9YsZ1K4kjRaHU2Lk2X/An2k8yopVKKDjycx1obDTIo3gFHbMLMbBbPNSlj1/Hu5BQo5X@dsQetej112sI@rtyxiE1isr10bIviX@p2MvdrA2YPnH4PHX@ivxgFPAwea8D2mc9WSytkvzreBDieqKIi0pIMHMiy2TmVwYDlZSd50GwYal2VElZkIvnybyMTMmMSg5SLtha5QFIspfNl6UxwGUNI50fJ5oaDEuXnv7Hjgt0AuxN0m6UVJCrvRJxPtK6im/Y9Bgyb1rRMgUlTqgGNORYu5vl/nR5IT5AU9V/0BRIvNgEySmYQvdO0GKDT4m7e334GkjTEVI4dklr8I8cP2xNshoMCwJCwJGTqRVNPKJMOjyOzQ43aJHxAGlXA8QcOawUi5EVX/I4fxCb4KfoTpYHFhfGEH0ArFTgpENILHQgf01bIZ@baQaV@oPYQjR6ZJp@78IwZANIWgT7xHGikwkYKcCvnc6YmaIQhnZQIADnrmHoWKswUeRymA6C1xPpmy8gtdypLQQmEmSz/Aahc4kiWbgbFBUIVVbZQqOewvnWDtFN4Ltbt391bXEas7gsXmsxr525/pNhSXepMVzUT9THEyote0aHMsH9Mp8mcqKrjbNr7Y/pWllJy3T/RWldCVxKBV3ULLgjXoWlVzL5X1v/UlT8pVJU1FfUuot2tn0yOdX3tKM3dusuJTvSoRAOwYABCz97BX8oqKiXTgA6tl7ulvAQj1jTbY6hHCOELHvKriOQ5yrmz4lYEDmX9XTi1B/Ipg/Nnzx4H1Al7gN@Dy9NOtz99ZBFHTfJ9SOcfEkQnjCBeEASIEbJLFAs8TWFmPccUP1xxPU8gzbhxyaxMoJxg4eRjucTdDP7bylpiqkWu0NYLC9FEOfR25cOw23FLb1hmFK4UsVTgyBpSgJYR1Ya8FhJ@LQrtiPZF7CWEE3PihJJLEof8Lpz0hI9XuFZFc8R8iL@N0H3OrWi@dMYQeADlbOnDk6inwugeSqP5KnaWBou5G0yhf0i2l1YMOiPGDKhByUpEnWhu9V@caoi9M4G8IZLkRoDTXPD7SI4Cjk60CrlpRbbjJEPT4Z7tT7jWWsXT9kvQ4s6cbyAHpgyls4IJQ6jpw0GvLyJnIHm374HolkwGBMdj3J@hL0oggwHHfQnks4O/UM0Qx@OJff@AjDweQZ@4LKRk5yDlKGJX82snLC@Bm6bjQf5oahFfTiFT4utJxUQaKztYh/kw/KlAw72YhxJPHQZ7FSIGP@rMeGyvJ1p5tQbq7DlwpKVd6nXzc4SoImSj8AMOGn/dweiPK6jK94bkKZqrALnWggNYpKGwESHMXkx/UTJI2lxL9Kxzw1ETrfAeJE8bIPeaGG/EQjtuMcyqaWC0KA61eKJTKZCUJ3UPCkqLNugbFwa7Q9@ImtxxgL5IqxAGEe/DlBa0yr6PhD6ZDwv0RK31uEW0TatXfaaddQiItbtOyMG6bLAA0R7a4t@yYdRTLO07t3cVwZAHtGEIPgFYR4vOr5JNYRKpgMHk3nUhk@2MV85yAkoRJ3jTgqbmCTCVGOzNJgZrh2lQuY0Ihp3XiDVpJfyd8zsvg6fEpz3cR7bvTZ1Zg0CmqcfqADiMn0Y23hLTqqhFS7IYAlIHWh4l1be2rgYnS9@2lieitGf@9bnZPWnVkyBdNzYGl5P67Ud6Oj5uFdWVe3dO6HvD1qvPrRH2aIVNMD@/f/X2iwDMg6XSQY9hikfzzgI70Ietq69sdvXlf199fnO9f8N//IPaJMLYp8uvbPj@WqE1HYRj1mJtCFSQPDWMGSDuWOHsjh3DNK@Vqj1ac7vteGSm4kuC@GLlOZtWflebLKC8PQ@ITNqXozQgVXit0juk5lNdTcYhA1knCWRA2bDoh4QzQ08G/hXCTbKbzAdgAfcaB5WaROjGNN6XS6x9mtG1OsH9Bnnt2OJ3ELRwUkoOEYO6pusjo5a4CceFPpph70ESGuQPJYtmH0lWZcJQE4W14PhptWc05O7pc8wqW@1fHrq0qkdZB2Z57Bn5@3YUTy7s4@N@l75df/z0f@bHX8zrN58@v7l6dfPm2nz16d1Fd9MVn78S1K@e3wZZQbCzYj5p3/ngtYC0lrGFpilGHZrxPsFvkQUpCSjThTWZQIIZbWl/9JA6wgHItH1t/vru47N@awQkvXe81QaLR4/Dkg8dNeMF6bx7SN0mDDXIKfOiJKtWA2lbB27peIt01JKBkaK4gFTUgYF90apBo1cXJ5aMJELK4dyReT600E2vrBk3l/wOZmgD9gw64@6YTyJn5lmQT3EoxFTisRqx5YE6w6gm2e/BDgQ5nr1cTTjSQjzCBARdnCwuyb8hJZjwZerOhu3@YFRKcWjlpjkvrkhKaWYg9gGmaA6dk07npFVBiJwaiWAvXkjgA7IgxV@VJ2kyU01nJB3xJD2nVnZ6MtdXJk3JMmTuzbrChOohJbiFncxhKLWDsCVj2xMpcHZug1EDH5flYmBvViwGYL6xeVCCh4Cw5KVCmMOboNZOHJUQBZZXLHPAjkJuuSU0cyidFEvTrelihXixqEx5xk@hCiTWmRfhyapP5Lt33HYwVJ2AMwZVjTvzIFAxwdA4Hmevvnx58/nG/PDlrQYhG9J4N5rp7J/pQDygt9B@okrI6h@UKtK8eDIYCDLZFJqC1hy@otk6bntOLRjVCdMO2RNszw4h9Y7ZIcR9ahf7pmiqmeb7dx/fmCa@yHb4E/sQzQbsn4cpoIQi0gAAas6q6LD9VYxLykQIbo1jIcSsZfqFNLvYFobKX4v6cOXhCofJw9APNcSjq9CP7LFCeEI2ZUkeHuo56PcfQXw5Qg@h6BAfEv5zVJ8Verv@@4dP2kYvInmyIVQoeXxAiCYsuMsSQVDypwipZY/pK470a0Wvba5eAtoVaM9LMz5Ty0@fy4rT5/kah2pyFUqtG6x6/ZdiVSCKB4O8qg4GiBEA8ijBNzQ2qm6z6r84be4IAEodNTaqbrN60es3dwQApY4aG1W3WfW6/edbZAcQZeE1Nqtptep3nzfI3KONtvOaWulyzLFlL0AHzxGXwcTvOuo9DOB8YrrWDLImcGcNoPacA2IwsTvfmVyyy@Ig/mtJ/2bCVcMSmp5Ig5kw5cBXE6BYz5mZgNsCJW2ghA2K89gE3BYoqeglbFCcxybgtkAl2lxmFcoLvArIbXCJypbZhfICvwKyHk6sqIJvNGP28YZiOUxiWJagyDoPggcionBGYIMBzGcna5jT4hzYXoUh9@x7TeLFj4wa1PSSdZWa5CUbqBGFjyVifnGDKnJOTmTbXglbRn4JJ2ohewdam8MFqYUJs2XcYjVj2VbttowHVwqXmFSfSypf0xaS/IL7KzeQVV1mfYpdqCstiSD0sknXSCMK7jIbMAnwopgpMFwF4ebaDydRBZjbVdnBBWgBwzdByK7QBGHIumflFVIhiooKoTY3b1C7UO8yECjjeWxyeGVg5Tq@tiVpBdpkMQRQXemI9Mflrg0J/FNckgdGt7eBSaltir0R7TVt3l8wCL9//MGSb@gllK9o5srXzCSrmE3UGpMZB9M5a2nG51k/BmYBRhMM9G6QRzOqcrWqFkCgQV7LIG9zeXl5ViDryw50ObvQ5exNlyN@V9N1vYu8qOOtAsNu9hMYkGQIxayS2C6kOTuR5uxNmkOkOTWk/W0XoRGerULDfvYTGtJkiKCRI63GwJS8@YZWrRFblfncSIeE@6lH2s2R7pacA00SXPnC8WHywrFtea2YjTn7nYf@T4dVuK1V7Ev0P0M2QasRT2HONnrI75ci2I3/nt5f1OibpT@Ulg3EILy/oQNWFBPPqpbblxQnAchi56qjU5b1NYSofmUZXytoW@VW0G2Yd5zqMogmY4dDIPDnXJ24WDoWHaOC1B17@OMCekCXqVn4JrKj06zIOavdhEMW/5u1QzZgYR7q8axKuL9uEe4PE9z1Dxfc9dcIDtyMFuogPfGwXYTvrx18IW4IosRXg99LWQrtfooH5nLfxxUyliQABg0QAHfsBDFpY32X/sHuvnv/f9mp/@KuWJqdaEmuRFvfahaTI11S7hrERIHwTVUzlVrt/QdxOtQtkllBqqLxisKrfWV4N6Bddc3x3dhvQpC@Mv5VKGq1lxIvawEmg4uBWuV76sXBFGvmtePWqxqAnOPH0ydP6eBJevpEL0aDfY6fHOo7cCwdQ5YJf2EiiOGBkB3ak9CV8yQUewpj4RWMJtqii0XxiwMm4EDQOWh/u9F6YjELD53tqKzVdAuCqo7EfNF3xSGt7nW4q8HloIaeOHY1otMzZ5UNTk7Qu4sWeJQGBIFCoMU5caKmilo16cBWezdaUaMNvjZ2o/2G7WB2WtMmOZrzn@g43AYc4nQNBDJABnJwMZL9W3iT/hZvQk6kp7iPnY6gfpvH2NVi3ry9uq5yE@XYWmNBMNsLUX0sceoM34TDrz1xYA74/W1VnQplp3K0kERT10M6VYgdroU@YjTQbC5KgxmCr5COCeFCXRcFdFREFNTYTK6PyKeToWX89G4eHotb4ZS/BtVjnZhilEtCH6VgPtozPllo0fgQ@YLkcS2lcu2i2Iod09M4KYp9mgHJbpo9RZFNaoKsGkDzHvkHiPkdnaD4em1SoIYzijQxemPUUg3vZ2gUChnbjOI7mJk8aCLfWAWrajveHe56YWhez8HSUPUvWa8yNqvO16J3LoUa0a8IKaF7Ith4yzgRfDJWlkMNKQFpHBHL2Ufq6tnqbwr5aWQLRWSTob1ROjXmFPYymYWUG9S9o0AH3DNBhT2Kir3mNo44AAbqpgnQOsiFQE4uIT34TrjP9s96FuJM9o08/P7t2U7N4fi9E54Ps69PeLri7HxPHJ4f0Xnz2twnUZBYJDHaJjkuiefo9eRLszmJtjL9WeyU@KBibNDi0LPp6WH8L985A/oALmeP2VpelihIlKLZlyf3nzXJUjl3f51kgv09fG2Sc1WTmz/W/5@eeJWln1/3G45SUqf48j7QpZWm99kbAur2QY5nYUxE6IzH591LjVbw6sBJZ1Lo3hZoOWApfH8LfDo0aYtn5RbFvS4uDwgq6VbFsiNFCZ6Xj8zEoKouFYMqPATdKw@56PW4VKfIvLj1Ippc5gNhXhB0ik@Eszwxyb5elqBt5JIaBCxDUFMYfZHaod7J7a9k5@syOfT5IDG0EUW3oNfqqh2eZO@dwZ9zXNc@Y8fH6yppga/c56RrVT6Px1@rs2blSKw4oSnPxCqHYtn6DGmoORWbW95UNBiFIc504CYUHpRVrYFqqxclpRSLRk4naeuUonDANgN7rFOJT/76y9Jff1WGSbVj1PzxWZU6jcumo9jFuN4uxrV2cXxMSJv4l@YwrjIHEQYxFbMq1DGIw4kzncp15PSbQIWK0Md15EtaYm63nSrKQ3mKXiwL41JE9QK4NhbLzDSLrb3DSMVk7TLoYfOIi9fKAss7v7lk40jDfRragba9uMEFCgVYF1yzOBKM80H5OoC6W25U3j1X5VtEmeOlZXTqGq9EkgXaOOrgo4bJCnUl7lmiZ72Y0HomdYZql2soSJAt6QvMg@YKcNqw3EmFZJ4EoTVzLXxrgAXy5CQq0UHlrkQ8l/sS8HAuUIImw7eiCpEwxFuR5@rzDSiLuJIh55wMlgfSxG13VZ46hWHj1VTCnTWfO0rJT4YPyT/KpFadhUno82xgE8lmI4qIjhnNSlJsQDXKRFBWlZ@ourjEPEH2dJQM59xJVQx61WS17EfCpCqxy3QAnD1OH8R9HvRCB0vPHdYJ6xZoWPpn8PccCEKWbqvtexwNb0fi2hd63J8geekI9p6PSczl8dyfbMdXJtxgt12hqwoDBv7qVrMhLwrpjoa3XWSHeGnepFuIcL/AcE96jJ0sqtF/BwqrqJSONVesZ9eeyIJd2ShkDP8ydhbV7JCbS1naWblya7H0vlDdJK0ohe6eUviOkiisVBUEc5GkN8LEjGJqdwxz5eZTJPg5XFe9vL2ml7Jhol9VuahcyNjJwF87nhXeMxgF3@Ne7FB@K053bsk8oXFyYxz3Omtn4QR84lgdP5yd4LeTN8ulE@Akz16Fd9wMfHzlM59IP5F9tNfUh/k1nmQhh3PRzXRDDOcCh3NRM5wQl4aLxIcsRmc7dpolbbe5pI0rSdutSNrq9Dl9q7F@VX31UkYewIqvw73UNI4Z3K3I4GpCISR6BL9lJf47CK8sROkTZAF5AvlYv1xPEujV19/ijWteXLNIX7eysCt2KYEtUDUuOI376zTNuKXYLx1RA130Lif4hcZuBdAfF2kOQ8MPfbTBhzQpQTZzqRNc/Q7HVpknWgaiPWfrbUyCg0guvBpXehnccrecZSOS5kN3eYsMchYJcwwR7YN0DhVsI/k7m8f3MZPcRC5GPQgaJnL/Ana2soQOdQtD9Rq41bCLXAWCmQB1EnkJ9P/MMd4h68DhvyikFfo2L9KWl4jJBme79XOeXFxYO4GpXUjHu3vi7OLBeHT2jSb@/UaqaZSI7C3j9LjHhvHuGe53ZlTJUFN@c7kpXWkvAwoFrW/NSsVicAWATIuOt@OHfLwKwa3swas80gg@fuc9/N3y4SuftpgZHk0Sl3DsNhH/2iwUBwNaqJdbJiqpN6/FPx60Wi1l5Fqu5Xh0R0B6oPdJdoPIgCWnuvEGhuPjg4PyzSkHdkOZOEV8QCJZOmO7I44Hs6T@SFTZgTj1nBUf2HhAmW9ijrs7CHMkjifbeAoY69JTJXfWsssOu4f11T122Guo7rPDfkP16XN2ePq8CX3/JXTQf9nUxYtT6OTFaQMIHs06hF8FEHpZGarpeip2SBtdNSB4KJwdxvD7sEJ@h9mtEnSC@5B5/syR/41DPfozFEeEkjedRj/wKJA4/A2GfvDkf4SqdMb@yptEdBpPE1dyZXXr0AqsEAGSKmSy8tK3I@XeN3mwfXX6HHfiRBw8fa6n9wSLm6v/fvoc37z11Euc5O1mtBEKXG3q71zWNuQZHWAMzwJBPKPuCrdaemP0FgCgXMgMOIRUsn@GgQZN5Kg3daKHyN@wa4jrnTkYHg@tmJcuqA5xc84Rt0FjKJfUlW7/TDt@y2Mc/ByizXiJV1zn7oAtCQhgcGpC5zbgS7EHMCGIaxIKvlCuhmaTleI3KkZTyYrxGxWjeWTF@E0ggS7zK9/qdX8P4r9y0OXx6SX2@B5I7r9RsP7jMG2l3Dcqd4YSochr/STLVCkoyW5HVf6bz1Bo1Bj/wYe43T3/j4NqFcCl9VZsm7Q7yDZbM2rk9Q88hebJFqhy2azqY4YDgw1GzCZCx1EGkLfMIcIgDW4jBPbLy50AekEm/qmq5uLk3IXkh6yhCk4dxfS5CpAm7PI/6WSc01KU4t/wk78ZKHF25OANCiIjSr7G2XE90jAFkM4zlSFT1VVA6SBTGTRVZwWUzmERaOnwQe7fMHSp5RYmejsz0dudid7uTPS2MNHbhYn@zkz0d2eivzsT/YwJPa8151kAu3wKpjQEz9IdGSISnhdjHIDwIVVzGQWrQPC@4qy/0jXmwyQaqFf6438eyxK5x8I9l/bgZOx4J8vlnUsPjfdeQo554OCthniXqGnSrW@miWmhacr/@CFuv/7zz/8H), it is not runnable).

---

**Update 2**. Implemented one more version, also in C++/Cython. Now it is pure GMP (C library) based. And there is no Python interaction while computing.

It appeared that this solution is quite simple and fastest of all. To remind my fastest solution above in C++ was based on [Montgomery Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/montgomery-reduction-algorithm) and [Sliding Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Sliding-window_method) variant of Binary Exponentiation and that solution was `19x` times faster than pure Python single-threaded variant.

And current solution which is C++/GMP based is `25.4x` times faster than single threaded Python. Of course it is parallelized using OpenMP. Its code is quite simple, I provide only a code of this single C++ function down below due to StackOverflow post size limit. Full code is provided also below, hosted at external PasteBin web-service.

Precise timings of all methods (new method is called `Cython_Gmp_Parallel`):

```
reg_win = 4 (330 redcs), slide_win = 5 (321 redcs)

Python                           : time 162.81 sec, boost  1.00
Python_Parallel                  : time  37.92 sec, boost  4.29, Correct
Gmp                              : time  56.57 sec, boost  2.88, Correct
Gmp_Parallel                     : time  15.13 sec, boost 10.76, Correct
Redc_Div_Parallel                : time  34.81 sec, boost  4.68, Correct
Redc_Barrett_Parallel            : time  67.23 sec, boost  2.42, Correct
Redc_Montgomery_Parallel         : time  86.69 sec, boost  1.88, Correct
Cython_Redc_Barrett_Parallel     : time  13.96 sec, boost 11.66, Correct
Cython_Redc_Montgomery_Parallel  : time   8.31 sec, boost 19.58, Correct
Cython_Gmp_Parallel              : time   6.40 sec, boost 25.42, Correct
```

**Full code** hosted at PasteBin [is here](https://pastebin.com/raw/91FpiCeN).

And just a code of single C++ function, which is quite short:

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h>
// .... And several other includes

void PowModGmpC(
    uint64_t * bs0, uint64_t bs_words, uint64_t cnt, const uint64_t * e0,
    uint64_t e_words, const uint64_t * m0, uint64_t m_words) {
    
    auto ToL = [](void const * x, size_t c) {
        mpz_class r;
        mpz_import(r.get_mpz_t(), c / 8, -1, 8, 0, 0, x);
        return r;
    };
    auto ToW = [](mpz_class const & x, void * y, size_t c) {
        size_t cnt = 0;
        mpz_export(y, &cnt, -1, 8, 0, 0, x.get_mpz_t());
    };
    
    mpz_class const
        e = ToL(e0, e_words * sizeof(u64)),
        m = ToL(m0, m_words * sizeof(u64));
    
    std::span<u64> bs(bs0, bs_words * cnt);
    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt * bs_words; i += bs_words) {
        mpz_class b = ToL(&bs[i], bs_words * sizeof(u64)), r;
        mpz_powm(r.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t(), e.get_mpz_t(), m.get_mpz_t());
        ToW(r, &bs[i], bs_words * sizeof(u64));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). Doesn't seem like your implementation is correct. Moving the those two statements out of else have improved the performance significantly.

This is what I have from Wikipedia

```
def modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus):
    if modulus == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        result = 1
        base = base % modulus
        while exponent > 0:
            if exponent % 2 == 1:
                result = (result * base) % modulus
            exponent = exponent >> 1
            base = (base * base) % modulus
        return result
```

**Output:**

```
print(modular_pow(4, 13, 497))
```

> 445

Comment: This is the version I have. Above was a copy error, as you could see with the indentation, the statements where already outside of the else-statement. The else-statement contained a debugging-print for test-purposes, that I removed.
This is slower than Python's pow.

Comment: @torpedo give me an input where it was significantly slow. For me it ran pretty fast.

Comment: @torpedo It took me ~1.14 minutes to run `print(modular_pow(4, 13, 497))` 100000000 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windowed NAF method to precompute a^2, a^3,...,a^(2^w-1).  Now instead of n products and squaring you have n/w rounds of products.  For example, in 256-bit modexp, with w=4, we make 6 precomputations.  But instead of 256 squarings and products, we have 256/4=64 of products.  At the cost of 14 precomputations it is a serious savings.  Now 4 bits is 2^4=16 possible values.  But NAF represents these in range -w+1..w-1.  Note negative exponents require modular inverse of a^(-1).  So just using the encoding to scale positive values is more optimal than extra multiplication or need to compute modular inverse.  Note a^0 and a^1 do not require computation.

Some precomputations might be optimized based on the exponent in NAF form as you know before hand exactly which values will be needed.

The w value must be adjusted based on exponentiation but size.  The optimal value can be computed based on n/w vs. 2^w-1, or determined empirically.

I'm surprised fixed exponent aspect of the problem was not addressed yet.  There are also a couple papers on this exact topic.  The same techniques are used in elliptic curve scalar multiplication albeit there typicslly the point similar to the base is fixed rather than the scalar equivalent to exponent here.  The same method works on fixed base but the precomputations can be done offline and reused more efficiently whereas with exponent, they are done on the fly.